# Outlook 2007 Delivery Receipt -- how to direct these receipts to a folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

In outlook, you can request 'delivery receipts' and 'read receipts'.  I like the delivery receipts, but not enough to have them clutter my inbox.  I've made a rule to filter these over to an 'ack' folder based on the words

> Return Receipt

in the body. However, this rule never works to redirect storage of these receipts into the 'ack' folder.  Anybody know how to make this filter work?

Comment: It works in Outlook 2003 by running the rule on the subject line.  Try modifying your rule to run when matching the subject line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Outlook 2007 is somewhat blind to the Return Receipts, I had to create a kludgy rule to catch them.  I tell outlook to look for inbound messages between 5 and 11 KB in size.  I only ask a certain client to give return receipts.  So I additionally limit the filtering/moving of emails to those that originate from the client's domain.